# Is a creature immune to blindness affected by Fog Cloud (or other Heavy Obscurement)?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions

"A heavily obscured area—such as Darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage—blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from the Blinded condition when trying to see something in that area."

So is a creature immune to the Blinded condition affected by Fog Cloud or Cloudkill?

Comment: Note the [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) on Heavily Obscured : *A heavily
obscured area doesn’t blind you, but you
are effectively blinded when you try to see
something obscured by it*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Blinded vs "Effectively Blinded"

*Blinded* is a condition that is inflicted upon a creature.
"Effectively Blinded" is a behaviour that a creature must follow even though it is not under the *Blinded* condition.

Immunity to being blinded only means that they *cannot suffer from that condition*. They can still encounter situations where objects and entities are obscured from their vision. In those cases the rules for targeting while blinded apply but only when attempting to target entities obscured by the fog.

Answer (score 11):

## Immunity to the Blinded condition does not allow you to see through Fog Cloud, etc.

If the effect does not specifically impose the Blinded condition, a creature immune to the Blinded condition is still affected by the Fog/Darkness/whatever.

Rules only do exactly what they say, so while the creature is *effectively* suffering from the Blinded condition, they are not actually Blinded, so their immunity does not apply.

Comment: @Destruktor I was answering 'No' to the question stated in your body. I.e. `So is a creature immune to the Blinded condition able to see through a Fog Cloud or Cloudkill?`

Comment: Yes, the question has both a positive and negative variant of the same question, so adding a quote of the question being answered would help to clarify.